Topological magnon bands, chiral edge states and broken time-reversal symmetry
The existence of topological magnon bands was initially proposed within a spin model in which a DM term gaps out the Dirac points (breaks inversion symmetry). At the level of spin wave theory, or a theory of non-interacting magnons, people have shown that this model is equivalent to the Haldane model on the honeycomb lattice. The first proposal was given in 2016 by these papers:
https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/28/38/386001
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.227201
There's also a nice review on the topic:
https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-conmatphys-031620-104715
In all these papers they plot the edge states on a slab geometry, i.e. choosing periodic boundary conditions only in one direction, and show two chiral edge states. This is somewhat confusing since in these systems there's no time-reversal symmetry and naively I would not expect a pair of edge states, but rather one edge state connecting the conduction and valence bands. Can someone please explain why there is a pair of chiral edge states in such models of topological magnon bands?

If you are looking at say Fig. 4(a) in J. Phys.: Condens. Matter 28 386001 or Fig. 1(b) in PRL 117, 227201, the way they get the band structure is by diagonalizing the Hamiltonian on a slab geometry, as you point out. In their notation, you have a finite width in the $y$ direction and infinite system size in the $x$ direction.
The two edge states in their figures is consistent with the Chern insulator.
In a (time-reversal symmetry broken) Chern insulator such as the Haldane honeycomb model, you have one chiral edge state per edge. Since we are in the slab geometry, you have two edges and therefore two chiral edge states with opposite velocity. If you look at the real-space wavefunction for these edge states, you will see that it is exponentially localized to one of the edges -- the edge corresponding to your choice of branch.
